# Convert List<Document> to Map<String, List<Document>> grouped-by a variable in the Document object with Java 8 streams (lamda) in one line

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of objects and I want to convert it into a Map which is grouped by one variable in the object. Below is lengthy code I got to. Can someone help me do this in one line?

```
    List<Document> all = repo.getAllDocuments();

    List<String> ids = all.parallelStream()
            .map(obj -> obj.getFor().getOpp().Id())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Map<String, List<Document>> map = new HashMap<>();

    ids.forEach(id -> map.put(id, all.parallelStream()
            .filter(obj -> obj.getFor().getOpp().getId().equals(id))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: You can use something like: Map<String, List<Document>> map = all.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy( obj -> obj.getFor().getOpp().getId()));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```java
Map<String, List<Document>> map = 
    repo.getAllDocuments()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(doc -> doc.getFor().getOpp().getId()));
```